# HTML tables: making 'em stick

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm wanting a whole table of 50px by 50px images, and these images need to stick to each other to make an apparent bigger image. So right now I've gotten them to stick horizontally, but not vertically, like so:

[image: Image of what I'm talking about]

As you can see I'm having a problem getting rid of **area A** (red arrow)

My code looks like this right now:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr height="50px">
     <td width="50px" height="50px">
        <img src="image.png" height="50px" width="50px" />
     </td>
     <!-- etc --> 
   </tr>
   <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

What CSS/HTML code should I use to change the height? According to Chrome element inspector, the height of the `<td>` element is 55px. (arb?)

**EDIT**: forgot I'm already setting cellpadding and spacing to 0. The image above is with them both at zero. Updated code sample.

**EDIT**: "Area A" doesn't exist in IE. Screenshot from Chrome.

Comment: have you tried `table{border-collapse:collapse;}`?

Comment: Have you a live example of this?

Comment: have you remove the cellpadding cellspacing? `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`

Comment: @kyle-sevenoaks sorry, no live demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images align to the baseline of text, leaving space below the text for any descenders (on letters such as y and g). You can use a css style of  `display: block;` for images to prevent this behaviour.

In your example, the following will work:

```
table img
{
    display:block;
}
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td
{
    padding: 0;
}
```

You do not need to specify `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`, nor the heights and widths of the `tr` and `td` elements.

It may make sense to specify a css class on your table so that these styles only impact the desired elements.

e.g. `<table class="tiledImages">` in your html and then `table.tiledImages` in your css.

---

If you just need to repeat your image, have you considered just setting it as a `background-image` for a `div` element?

```
div
{
    width: 400px; /* example width */
    height: 400px; /* example height */
    background-image: url(image.png);
}
```

Comment: +1 - this is definetly an issue with using some DTDs, causing this kind of gaps.

Comment: @HBublitz: This is nothing to do with DTDs, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! you were right, it was the text align of the image. inserting display:block worked great. ^.^

Answer (score 1):

Do you have attributes for cellpadding and cellspacing in your table-definition: 
`<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">` ?

Comment: I tried this, but didn't help. Interestingly, this does work in IE, but not in chrome

Answer (score 1):

I'd say get rid of the height and width settings then use css to cause the table to collapse all of the borders.

Something like

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

The above does 2 things.  First, it causes all of the table borders to collapse down to get rid of the default borders that certain browsers use.

Second, it  makes the table draw faster because the browser only has to compute the first row, so the table starts displaying almost immediately.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't help. Interestingly, this does work in IE, but not in chrome

Comment: @Matt: Change your doctype to either strict or html 5... <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

Set cellpadding and cellspacing of the table to 0 to remove the gap.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table>
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't help. Interestingly, this does work in IE, but not in chrome